# Aspect Ratio issue for image in iOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

When i try to add image in imageView, it might be got stretch. My imageView size is fixed.

So, i add like as follow:

```
[imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

But if the image is sometimes cut off, small. So, image view got blank view above the image if image is small.

**How can I take image as per image view without pixelated or stretch??**

Comment: you can set ur imageview width and height depend upon the image width and height example--image.size.height;image.size.width;

Answer (score 3):

try [[yourimageview layer] setmasktobounds:yes];

Answer (score 2):

`UIViewContentModeCenter`

> Centers the content in the view’s bounds, keeping the proportions the
>   same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But by this my image is got very small.

Comment: That's because your image is small. You have to choose to either a) pixalate it or b) display it small.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I already tried this but does not solve the problem.

Comment: Can you change the size of the image view?  Find the largest dimension of the image. If you have a max for how big the image view can be, make the image view that size in the dimension the image is largest in, then calculate how large the other dimension should be in order to preserve aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Just Check For maximum size of image and if its small then adjust size of imageview according to image.

here image is **`UIImage`** which is actually image to set on **`UIImageView`**

```
    if(img.size.width < imgView.superview.frame.size.width ||
       img.size.height < imgView.superview.frame.size.height)
    {
       [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,img.size.width,img.size.height)];
       [imgView setCenter:imgView.superview.center];
    }
     [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```